# Database relation in 3NF?

Tags: database, relational-database, normalization, 3nf

I have following relation. A company has several employees. Each employee is defined by its employee number `ENr` and he is living on an address `EAddress` with a ZipCode `ZZipCode`. The City with the ZipCode is an own table because otherwise there is redundancy in table Employee. Therefore `ZZipCode` is a foreign key in Employee.

A Group is defined by its `GGroupId`, therefore that is the primary key. Each group has one group leader which can be any employee. Therefore `ENr` is a foreign key.

Each employee can work on none, one or more groups. For this reason the table `GroupMember` exists where the the tuple `ENr` and `GGroupID` define the primary key and both are foreign keys (I cannot do both, bold and italic).

And last, a product is defined by its product id `PId` and is associated to a group `GGroupID`.

Well here are the relations for that written description.

> Employe(**ENr**, EName, EGender, EAddress, *ZZipCode*, ESocNr,
>   ESalery) 
>  Group(**GGroupId**, GName, GCostNr, *ENr*) 
>   GroupMember(**ENr**, **GGroupID**) #both members are foreign keys
>   too!
>  Product(**PId**, PName, PPrice, *GGRoupId*)
>   Zip(**ZZipCode**, ZCityName, *SStateID*) 
>  State(**SStateID**,
>   SStateName)

For clarification: **bold** members are primary keys and *italic* members are foreign keys.

I tried to put that relation into `3NF`. Can anyone confirm that this is right?

Comment: Not sure about 3NF but it is normalized, I can't find better relations

Comment: What form of confirmation do you want?  I mean, is it enough to say 'Yes, it is'? :)

Comment: Well, I tried to put that into 3NF. If it's not you can say me why not ;)

Comment: I can't, since I'm pretty much convinced it is 3NF.

Comment: Could it be that GName is also a determinant for Group and PName a determinant for Product (i.e. groups and products have unique names)? If that's the case then PName should be another key of Product and GName a key of Group in order to satisfy the requirements of 3NF.

Comment: What do you mean exactly? Yes, GGroupId and PId are unique. GName and PName could also be primary keys because they are unique too. But which key should they be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be good and normalised. I dont see any further division of the tables.